# Automatically call common initialization code without creating __init__.py file

Tags: python, scripting, python-module, pythonpath

I have two directories in my project:

```
project/
  src/
  scripts/
```

"src" contains my polished code, and "scripts" contains one-off Python scripts.

I would like all the scripts to have "../src" added to their sys.path, so that they can access the modules under the "src" tree. One way to do this is to write a scripts/__init__.py file, with the contents:

```
scripts/__init__.py:
  import sys
  sys.path.append("../src")
```

This works, but has the unwanted side-effect of putting all of my scripts in a package called "scripts". Is there some other way to get all my scripts to automatically call the above initialization code?

I could just edit the PYTHONPATH environment variable in my .bashrc, but I want my scripts to work out-of-the-box, without requiring the user to fiddle with PYTHONPATH. Also, I don't like having to make account-wide changes just to accommodate this one project.

Comment: Can you clarify what "one-off" means? Are the scripts meant to be exposed to the end-user after installing your app, or just convenience tools for development/testing only?

Comment: "This works, but has the unwanted side-effect of putting all of my scripts in a module called "scripts"". Could you explain why it is a problem? you can avoid the namespace effect by hacking the `__init__.py`, but it looks like you are fighting the language (which is bad :-))

Comment: @Simon: looks like you have the answer. Care to spell out what I need to do to "Hack the \_\_init\_\_.py"? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you have other plans for distribution, it might be worth putting together a basic [`setup.py`](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html) in your `src` folder. That way, you can run `setup.py develop` to have distutils put a *link* to your code onto your default path (meaning any changes you make will be reflected in-place without having to "reinstall", and all modules will "just work," no matter where your scripts are). It'd be a one-time step, but that's still one more step than zero, so it depends on whether that's more trouble than updating `.bashrc`. If you use [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip), the equivalent would be `pip install -e /path/to/src`.

The more-robust solution--especially if you're going to be mirroring/versioning these scripts on several developers' machines--is to do your development work inside a controlled virtual environment. It turns out virtualenv even has built-in [support for making your own bootstrap customizations](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv/1.6.4#creating-your-own-bootstrap-scripts). It seems like you'd just need an `after_install()` hook to either tweak `sitecustomize`, run `pip install -e`, or add a plain `.pth` file to site-packages. The custom bootstrap could live in your source control along with the other scripts, and would need to be run once for each developer's setup. You'd also have the normal benefits of using virtualenv (explicit dependency versioning, isolation from system-wide configuration, and standardization between disparate machines, to name a few).

If you *really* don't want to have any setup steps whatsoever and are willing to *only* run these scripts from inside the 'project' directory, then you could plop in an `__init__.py` as such:

```
project/
    src/
        some_module.py
    scripts/
        __init__.py # special "magic"
        some_script.py
```

And these are what your files could look like:

```
# file: project/src/some_module.py
print("importing %r" % __name__)

def some_function():
    print("called some_function() inside %s" % __name__)
--------------------------------------------------------
# file: project/scripts/some_script.py
import some_module

if __name__ == '__main__':
    some_module.some_function()
--------------------------------------------------------
# file: project/scripts/__init__.py
import sys
from os.path import dirname, abspath, join

print("doing magic!")
sys.path.insert(0, join(dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__))), 'src'))
```

Then you'd have to run your scripts like so:

```
[~/project] $ python -m scripts.some_script
doing magic!
importing 'some_module'
called some_function() inside some_module
```

Beware! The scripts can *only* be called like this from inside `project/`:

```
[~/otherdir] $ python -m scripts.some_script
ImportError: no module named scripts
```

To enable that, you're back to editing `.bashrc`, or using one of the options above. The last option should really be a last resort; as @Simon said, you're really fighting the language at that point.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your scripts to be runnable (I assume from the command line), they have to be on the path somewhere.

Something sounds odd about what you're trying to do though. Can you show us an example of exactly what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a file called 'pathHack.py' in the project dir and put something like this into it:

```
import os
import sys
pkgDir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.insert(os.path.join(pkgDir, 'scripts')
```

Then, in a python file in your project dir, start by:

```
import pathHack
```

And now you can import stuff from the scripts dir without the 'scripts.' prefix. If you have only one file in this directory, and you don't care about hiding this kind of thing, you may inline this snippet.