# Python __init__.py vs sys.path.append/insert

Tags: python, python-2.7, coding-style

I [know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/python-import-a-module-from-a-folder) there [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python) a [ton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161568/import-python-module-not-on-path) of [how-to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095037/why-use-sys-path-appendpath-instead-of-sys-path-insert1-path) import [Python modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722248/adding-folder-to-pythons-path-permanently) not in path, but I have yet to come across using Python's [__init.py__](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) vs sys.path.insert. Which method is better? Are there any obvious drawbacks to either, like performance? Is one more "Pythonic?"

One scenario I can think of, is I have a program that users download and put in whatever directory, so I don't know the absolute path (unless I get it programatically). The folder structure is

```
working dir
    __init__.py
    foo.py
    src/
        my_utils.py
        __init__.py
```

I don't see any difference between using __init__.py or changing sys.path. Is there any scenario you can think of where it would make a difference?

Part 2 of my question is, why do you have to do *anything* to be able to import modules from subdirectories? I'm fairly new to Python, so maybe I'm not understanding why fiddling with the path or creating **init** files is boilerplate. To me, it seems like an unnecessary complication. If I have "dir" in my current working directory and say "import dir.my_utils," I don't see why I would have to list everything I would want to be able to import in __init__.py.

Apologies if this is a duplicate, but I did search before posting.

**Edit:** Here's another useful link: [Automatically call common initialization code without creating __init__.py file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250632/automatically-call-common-initialization-code-without-creating-init-py-file)

Comment: What do you mean by "`__init.py__` vs `sys.path.insert`"? In what way are those things at all comparable?

Comment: so, I could put \__init__.py in each folder, so inside of foo.py, I could say "init src.my_utils." Alternatively, in foo.py, I could say "import sys; sys.path.insert(1, "path to src"); import my_utils"

Comment: Those still do completely different things.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'm missing the boat here if they're completely different. Could you explain how they are different, since in my mind, they can achieve the same result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**__init__.py** is used by the python interpreter to treat directories as packages. Packages play an important role in avoiding namespace collisions. If you read the section **6.4 Packages** from [Python Modules](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html), it helps to prevent directories with a common name from hiding other valid modules that occur later in the search path.

Hence, the package mechanism simplifies the task of importing packages. By using an `__init__.py` you can also do something like from `package.subpackage import *` which would be difficult or tedious to do if we were to keep appending to `sys.path` (in fact we will have to append all the possible modules).

As to answer the second part to your question - why do we need to do anything to treat directories as packages - well, there needs to be **some way** to tell python what should be allowed to import and what should not be. Also, you do not need to append anything to sys.path explicitly in case you have imported all the required modules at the beginning and that the  modules you require to be imported are already present on the **PYTHONPATH** environment variable.

Hopefully this answer sheds some light on your query.

Comment: Thanks, that does help a lot. I get the whole thing about namespace collisions, but pointing out `package.subpackage import *` as an example really clarifies it for me.

Comment: I've been looking for this solution for a long time but wasn't sure what I was even looking for. I hate how messy some of my program directories get with loads of modules. This helps me organize and clean it up simply by adding an `__init__.py` to each dir. Wonderful!