# Python import or create package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-packaging

i have a project structure like this:

```
python-modinfo
|--funcs
   |--__init__.py
   |--funcs.py
|--modules
   |--File-Operations
      |os_info.py
```

This is `__init__.py`:

```
from funcs.funcs import *
```

This is `os_info.py`:

```
import funcs.funcs
```

and this is terminal output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "os_info.py", line 1, in <module>
    import funcs.funcs
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'funcs'
```

What is my mistake while creating a python package

Comment: What command are you running? Maybe this helps (in particular point #4): https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/python_imports.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the `__init__.py` as `from . import funcs` as the `funcs.py Is In Current Directory`

Also try the same data in `os_info.py`

Comment: i have tried to write from . import funcs in __init__.py but i have gotten the same error and i am running os_info.py

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for a quick solution, do this in `os_info.py`:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('../../funcs')

from funcs import *
```

`os_info.py` won't know where `funcs.py` is located, therefore you need to tell it by providing the location.

Comment: thank you , it has worked but what does __init__.py file do if we can do it like this

Comment: To answer your question, I think this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779459/python-init-py-vs-sys-path-append-insert) explains it quite well.